# If $f(x_0) - f(x) \geq C(x-x_0), ~C>0$ then $f$ is decreasing?

Tags: calculus, analysis

I am reading a paper in analysis that appears to conclude some argument from the following, is it true? I could not prove or disprove it.

Let $f : [x_0,b) \to \mathbb{R}, b < \infty$ be a smooth function. If there is $C > 0$ such that
$$f(x_0) - f(x) \geq C(x-x_0),~\forall x \in [x_0,b)$$
can I guarantee that $f$ is decreasing?

Comment: I think you need some clarification on your variables. Am I correct in thinking that $x_0$ and $b$ are fixed constants in this problem, while $x$ varies between them?

Comment: please, who is downvoting comment to improve the question, I am not new in this site

Comment: @IsaacBrowne, you are correct, I shall edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, with $x_0=0$, $f(x_0)=0$,  and $C=1$, this merely states $f(x)\le -x$. We cannot conclude that $f$ is decreasing. Try $f(x)=-x+\cos(1000x)-1$.

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite your condition as
$$f(x) \leq f(x_0) - C(x - x_0)$$
This just says that the graph of $f(x)$ lies below the line of slope $-C$ containing $(x_0, f(x_0))$. For any $C$ it's easy to draw a graph of such a function that is not decreasing... just add a few "wiggles" to a decreasing function.